# python match string in line with regex and get a certain value

Tags: python, regex

I have the following which is part of a line in a log file

```
-FDH-11 TIP: - 146/S Q: 48
```

which I want to match with regex . Is there a way to get the value of Q in the above input. I am not sure the length between -FDH- and Q: is always the same. So ideally if I found -FDH- and Q: then get the value of Q.

Comment: `-FDH-.*?\bQ:\s*(\S+)`?

Comment: There can be more Q's between FDH or not? Would be ok to look just for the FDH and then for the Q?

Comment: @fernand0 No other Q in line and yes for the second part of your question. Thanks guys!!

Comment: @Gakis41 if there are no other instances of `Q:` in the string, the solution below provided by user3354059 should work for you.

Comment: @ctwheels on a regex editor it does the job right!!Thanks

Comment: @ctwheels yes I'll try both and see which does the job. This should be my first ride with regex!!

Comment: @Gakis41 I moved my comment to an answer.

Comment: @Gakis41 then you could  use `str.find` to know where is the positon for the desired output. Anyway the solution provided by @ctwheels seems to do the work.

Comment: ok last question, I should use re.match("-FDH-.*?\bQ:\s*(\S+)")   and then match.group?

Comment: @Gakis41 yes. You can actually click on the link in my answer below and on the left hand side there's a button labeled **Code Generator** and select python. It autogenerates code based on the regex.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/W7MafB/1)

```
-FDH-.*?\bQ:\s*(\S+)
```

---

### Explanation

- `-FDH-` Match this literally
- `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `Q:` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `(\S+)` Capture one or more non-whitespace characters into capture group 1

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use regex for this. If there is only one instance of "Q:" in the string, then you can just split on that and get the value after with the following:

```
str = "-FDH-11 TIP: - 146/S Q: 48"
parts = str.split("Q: ")
q_value = parts[1]
```

Comment: What if there's another variable with a `Q` in it like `GQ:`? The user also specified that it should be **after `-FDH-`**, which might imply that other instances exist where `Q` might be found. I do agree, however, that the OP should present us with more information about the string.

Comment: Then it wouldn't work which is why I said there can only be one instance of "Q:", but I was just trying to present the simplest and easiest to implement possible answer based on the above input. It won't work if your example occurs.

Comment: @ctwheels Q should be alone with a ":" in front.